# Pressing "Play" On Spotify through an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

I'm attempting to resume playback of a paused song on spotify through another app.

My current code:

```
Log.v(TAG, "Resuming Spotify");
Intent playSpotify = new Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY");
playSpotify.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
context.sendBroadcast(playSpotify);
```

This does not work. It will however pause a song that is currently playing.

Any advice/resources are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY
```

doesn't work anymore. use

```
com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.NEXT
```

Comment: However, this always skips to the next song. Isn't there another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent playSpotify = new Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.NEXT");
playSpotify.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
sendBroadcast(playSpotify);

playSpotify = new Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PREVIOUS");
playSpotify.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
sendBroadcast(playSpotify);
```

This may be a workaround.

UPDATE: 
Use `SpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi().resume();` Docs [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/)